# getting relative distance from origin to top left

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite

Below is an image that explains what I have:
[image: Describing image]

The brown square is the local origin of the Sprite I added. (I am *not* able to change the graphics!)

How would I get the X and Y distance between the two points in Flash AS3?
Or how can I programatically move the origin to the top left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [getBounds()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_fr/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29), it contains all you need.

An example :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class TestSquare extends Sprite
    {
        public function TestSquare()
        {
            var squareMc : Sprite = new Sprite;

            squareMc.graphics.lineStyle(5);
            squareMc.graphics.beginFill(0xFFAAAA);
            squareMc.graphics.drawRect(-20,-20,100,100);
            squareMc.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(squareMc);

            squareMc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        }

        protected function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Cancel offset
            var squareMc : DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;
            squareMc.x = -getTopLeftOffset(squareMc).x;
            squareMc.y = -getTopLeftOffset(squareMc).y;
        }

        // return top left offset
        public function getTopLeftOffset(target : DisplayObject) : Point
        {
            return target.getBounds(target).topLeft
        }
    }
}
```